# How did they get "King Kong" back to New York?

Tags: plot-explanation, king-kong-1933

It's a question audiences have been asking since 1933, so I thought this would be the perfect place for it :) Even Peter Jackson decided to side-step this particular issue in his remake.

[image]

How did they get "King Kong" back to New York?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The 1933 movie doesn't show how King Kong was transported, but according to [the script](http://atlantisonline.smfforfree2.com/index.php/topic,3029.20/wap2.html):

[image: script]

**They possibly towed the raft with the ship**, all the way to New York.

(Maybe *Peter Jackson* thought using a *raft* is a silly idea and therefore didn't include it in his version)

However, the *raft idea* was used in [**King Kong vs. Godzilla**](http://jellydonut25.hubpages.com/hub/King-Kong-vs-Godzilla-Kaiju-KomedyNot-Really-Funny#):

[image: raft]

In the [1976 version](http://reflectionsonfilmandtelevision.blogspot.co.at/2012/07/cult-movie-review-king-kong-1976.html) they **used an oil tanker** to transport *Kong:*

[image: oil tanker]

Comment: You are quick! In the 1976 version, Kong throws a tantrum in the hold of the ship at about 97 minutes in, and Jessica Lange falls through the grate into the hold while trying to calm him. It was my understanding that Peter Jackson followed the 1933 version scene by scene, so if there was nothing in 1933, there wouldn't be in Jackson's version.

Comment: @MaryJoFinch Nice comment, but you're quite wrong that Jackson followed the 1933 version "scene-by-scene". He was certainly in love with the original, but that didn't stop him from adding things and making changes. I believe he even shot a jokey answer to this question, but I can't find it now :-/

Comment: @MaryJoFinch - Interestingly _Naomi Watts_ did star in movie that was a _shot-for-shot_ remake two years later ([Funny Games](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Funny_Games_(2007_film)))